# create New site collection with new content database using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection

How to create a new site collection in existing web application but with new content database using powershell.

Comment: do you want to create new content database then new site collection or DB already created?

Comment: i want to create new content database , with new site collection , and after my purpose is dismount and mount existing sharepoint 2010 content database and upgrade sp 2010 content db to sp 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
New-SPSite -Url $url –ContentDatabase $ContentDatabase -Name $WebsiteName –Description $WebsiteDesc  -Template $Template -OwnerAlias $PrimaryLogin –OwnerEmail $PrimaryEmail
```

see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/89c90032-5be1-4fe6-8546-0114eaf018ca/site-collection-in-a-particular-content-database

Comment: i want to create publishing site ,in sp 2013 what is the template id for publishing site?

Comment: when i use above powershell its showing error 

New-SPSite : The content database could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPSite -Url "http://www.xxxxx/bi"  -ContentDatabase
"Wss_content_ ...

Comment: See the comment below by Waqas

Answer (score 9):

You have to create the Content Database 1st then you will be able to create new site collection.

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name "database name" -DatabaseServer "database server name"  -WebApplication "web app url"

$dbname = Get-SPContentDatabase "databasename"

New-SPSite -URL $site -OwnerAlias $owner1 -SecondaryOwnerAlias $owner2 -ContentDatabase $dbname -Template "BLANKINTERNET#0"
```

For site template codes, please check this blog.
http://www.funwithsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell/

Comment: Hi thanks, after that i want to mount sp 2010 content database to this new site collection and want to do migration to sharepoint 2013