# Create Site Collection with New Database

Tags: sharepoint-server, database

I want to create new site collection with new database.
I've to create new database for new site collection. the issue is, if I create new site collection. the site collection database is still on WSS_Content.
how to migrate the site collection to new database?

thank you in advance :)
sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **PowerShell** command for this.

Code:

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name "database name" -DatabaseServer "database server name"  -WebApplication "web app url"

$dbname = Get-SPContentDatabase "databasename"

New-SPSite -URL $site -OwnerAlias $owner1 -SecondaryOwnerAlias $owner2 -ContentDatabase $dbname -Template "STS#0"
```

You can pass your desired site template: http://www.jasjitchopra.com/sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell/

**Reference:** [create New site collection with new content database using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167050/create-new-site-collection-with-new-content-database-using-powershell)

---

We can do this **from Central Administration** also.

Steps:

- **Add content Database to Web Application**

  From **Central administration** screen --> **Application Management** --> click on **Manage Content Databases**.
- **Manage Content database settings**

  Before creating site-collection you have to change the status of each content database status to stopped and only required content database should show started.
- **Create Site Collection**

  After completion of above steps **don’t forget to change the other databases settings to Ready i.e. started**. To change the status click on Database name and change Database status from offline to ready and click ok. Repeat this step for all the Content databases those are offline.

Congratulation you have completed all the required steps.

**Reference:**

- http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-sitecollection-specific-content-database.html

Comment: Hi Dikesh, thank you for your answer. I want to ask, it is possible if I migrate without powershell?

Comment: This link will be useful.:http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-sitecollection-specific-content-database.html